How do I change an object's scale from another object's code in unity 2D
I am just starting out in unity and am trying to make a gameObject's scale using the code put in another gameObject
NoneText.Scale = 1.5; this was my line of code and I thought that meant I could change "NoneText's" scale. (I have NoneText added as a public GameObject)

If you'd go through some basic unity tutorial and look into the API this would probably answer itself ... GameObject has no Scale ... the Transform component has a localScale ..

You use the objects Transform to scale.
You could for example use Transform-localScale.
NoneText.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f);

